# Valores de array con variables if

Tags: php

tengo el siguiente array

```
$valor=array("numero"=>$numero,"telefono"=>$telefono)
```

y ahi sigue el array pero digamos que el valor de $numero no existe o es igual a cero como hago para que en el array entonces no aparezca si el valor es igual a empty o 0 y aparezca nada mas $valor=['telefono=>000000000] por decir un ejemplo

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es borrar esta parte del array `"numero"=>$numero,` si número es igual a `0` ? Me parece una intención extraña, vas a tener un array desfasado en el que en algunos casos existirá la clave `numero` y en otros no... ¿Seguro que estás planteando bien la lógica de tu programa?

Comment: lamentablemente se que es raro pero asi ocupo la programacion

Comment: Entiendo, pero muestra un trozo de tu array, con un sólo elemento no se puede ver cómo es exactamente, si son por ejemplo arrays dentro de un array general o como es, muestra dos o tres elementos para ver su estructura.

Comment: Concuerdo con @A.Cedano si desfasas el array, algunas veces aparecerá el valor y otras no! eso puede causar errores en tu codigo

Comment: Busca otra solución pero un array así sería peligroso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías obtener un nuevo array quitando los que son "ceros" o "empties" y luego trabajar con este nuevo array:

```
$valor=array("numero"=>0,"telefono"=>"12334");
$valor_final = array();

array_walk($valor, function($value, $key) use (&$valor_final) {
    if(!empty($value)){
        $valor_final[$key] = $value;
    }
});

print_r($valor_final) //mostrara el array que estabas buscando.
```

Saludos.